# Why i am getting no parser was explicitly specified. What changes to be made in the code?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(""<html>data</html>"")
```

Getting this warning:
BeautifulSoup([your markup])
to this:
BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")
markup_type=markup_type))

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup need to know what to parse
The thing you are giving maybe html, maybe xml,
both have somewhat different structures
So in the second argument of the function you need to specify that whether the given document is html/xml or whatever

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
src='"<html>data<//html>"'
soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"html.parser")
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: sir still getting that error.

Comment: can you explain your error?

Comment: Resolved by adding the type of document I want to parse as the second argument in the **BeautifulSoup()** function. Thanks to all for helping.